# Cannot send and receive data using BufferedReader/Writer on sockets

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, tcp

I am making a client-server application and am using the following code for the exchange of data b/w the server and clients.

Server's send and receive code:

```
public void run() {
     try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketNew.getInputStream()));
        String message=input.readLine();
        while(message.length()!=0)
        {
            for(Socket s:socs) //socs is a list containing all the connected sockets
            {
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
                writer.write(message);
            }
        }

     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Client's send method:

```
private void send_data() {

    BufferedWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write(this.name+textField.getText());
        textField.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client's receive method:

```
public  void receive_data(){
    BufferedReader input;
    try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String message=input.readLine();
        while(message.length()!=0)
        {console(message);}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am not having any data exchange b/w the server and the clients.Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

You are suffering from buffering: message is written in a buffer and probably never sent. Flush the writer to ensure it sends data:

```
    writer.write(...);
    writer.flush();
```

Also, BufferedReader.readLine reads lines. Lines have to be terminated with a line break, such as `\n`. It's not clear if you are sending line breaks.

Also, this is an infinite loop:

```
    String message=input.readLine();
    while(message.length()!=0) {
        /* code that does not modify message */
    }
```

Comment: I did that but to no avail.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you further. Try debugging your code.

Comment: I added the line breakers at the end and voila, the problem got solved.Thanks man.I also had to change the code a bit, as I was creating new buffers every time the user wanted to send and receive data.That was creating a problem.Thanks once again man.

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep creating new readers and writers. Use the same ones for the life of the socket. You're losing data in the old `BufferedReader` that is being discarded. These buffered things, err, buffer.

Also this:

```
String message=input.readLine();
while(message.length()!=0)
```

is, err, nonsense. Firstly you're not checking `message` for `null`, so you're going to get a `NullPointerException` at end of stream. Secondly, you aren't doing any further input inside the loop so if it doesn't throw NPE and the message isn't zero length it will loop forever.

Comment: I added the line breakers at the end and voila, the problem got solved.Thanks man.I also had to change the code a bit, as I was creating new buffers every time the user wanted to send and receive data.That was creating a problem.Thanks once again man.

Comment: Now I am having another problem.I have programmed the application in a way such that when I hit enter, the message is sent to the server.I have to hit enter twice for a message to be sent.Any suggestions?